# Get probabilistic state of a quantum circuit using Ry gate

Tags: qiskit, measurement, simulation

Starting with a 2 qubit (each initialized as $|00\rangle$) I need to apply an $R_y(\theta)$ gate to get the following probabilistics:

- 24% $|00\rangle$
- 56% $|01\rangle$
- 6%  $|10\rangle$
- 14% $|11\rangle$

I did the following, however, I am not getting exactly what is being asked for, an anyone help me and tell me where am I wrong?

```
from math import sqrt, acos, asin
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, Aer, transpile
from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram

prob = [0.24, 0.56, 0.06, 0.14]

qc = QuantumCircuit(2)

# Initialize both with state |00>
qc.initialize([1,0], 0)
qc.initialize([1,0], 1)

qc.ry(2 * acos(sqrt(prob[0])), 0)
qc.ry(2 * asin(sqrt(prob[2])), 1)

qc.measure_all()
display(qc.draw('mpl'))

backend = Aer.get_backend('aer_simulator') 

job_sim = backend.run(transpile(qc, backend), shots=1024) 
result = job_sim.result()     
plot_histogram(result.get_counts())
```

[image: results]

Comment: Have you tried increasing the amount of shots?

Answer (score 0):

this is how you do it without using vqe or qml, of course, you also can increase shots for accuracy.

```
from math import sqrt, acos, asin
import numpy as np
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, Aer, transpile
from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram

prob = np.sqrt([0.24, 0.56, 0.06, 0.14])

qc = QuantumCircuit(2)

# Initialize both with state |00>
# current initialize gate got reset in it, so is better to just use reset.
#qc.reset([0,1])

initial_state = prob/np.linalg.norm(prob)
qc.initialize(initial_state, [0,1])  

qc.measure_all()
display(transpile(qc, basis_gates=['ry','cx']).draw('mpl'))

backend = Aer.get_backend('aer_simulator') 

job_sim = backend.run(transpile(qc,basis_gates=['ry','cx']), shots=1024) 
result = job_sim.result()     
plot_histogram(result.get_counts())
```

after transpile:(you can't do basis_gates=['ry'])
[image]
you can do this to extract the needed ry params out

```
from qiskit.converters import circuit_to_dag
dag = circuit_to_dag(transpile(qc, basis_gates=['ry','cx']))
gates_param = []
for node in dag.op_nodes():
    gates_param.append(node.op.params)
for i in range(qc.num_qubits):
    print(gates_param[i][0])
```

```
qc.ry(1.98, 0)
qc.ry(0.927, 1)
```

[image]
1024 shots:
[image]
200000 shots:
[image]

Comment: Thanks!! One more thing. If I would have to do the math manually to get the values of each angle of the Ry(theta) gates I am not reaching the same result only with the Ry(theta) and replacing with [1 0] and the prob list. Can you explain me how you reached that result?

Comment: @gattes I think it is possible manually, but I don't understand how transpile or decompose work details and I am not good at math. I suggest search up 'quantum computing numpy', try to inverse the math function.

Comment: @gattes I found a detailed explanation how to do it. https://towardsdatascience.com/quantum-programming-for-non-mathematicians-bd6956d63b7c

Comment: @gattes accept answer will help alot